# How to hide Login/Pwd into shell?

Tags: linux, shell, shell-script, oracle-linux

I've a Shell script(.run) that let me to connect into Oracle sql :

```
    echo whenever sqlerror exit | sqlplus Login/Passwd@SERVER @"TABLE1.sql"

echo 'return code : ' $?
```

I'd like to hide **"Login/Passwd@SERVER"** by calling this into another shell or any other way please.
thanks for helping

Comment: You might need to use _expect_ ala TCL.  `sqlplus`/Oracle does not have password-less login for non-local connections to SYSOPER. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20144415/sqlplus-login-without-password. But _expect_ can send the password into the program when prompted.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to *hide* the value, you may put it in a variable in another script that you'll source:

```
. /path/to/other_script
echo whenever sqlerror exit | sqlplus "$HIDDEN" @"TABLE1.sql"
```

where `other_script` contains:

```
HIDDEN='Login/Passwd@SERVER'
```

but `other_script` will have to be readable...

Comment: This hides the values from history, but not from the process table. I'm not sure this will work for the user.

Comment: I want the 'Login/Passwd@SERVER' will be accessible only for the admin, so no one can see it except him.